# Can I start command prompt from my python script and send multiple outputs to it?

Tags: python

I am running a script and I want the script to start cmd.exe each time it runs. I want to print out information to the user. I need cmd because the script may be compiled as an executable and run as a background task so output may not be available.

I tried this, but I am hoping there's a better way

```
import os
os.system('start cmd /k echo checking in progress...')

os.system('cmd /k echo checking completed!!!')
```

The last line didn't print.

Comment: Why not just use `print()` and run the python script from command prompt using `python .\file.py`?

Comment: How about `os.system('echo sth like this')`?

Comment: It is not intended to be run from command prompt, it will be scheduled to run overnight, so there will be no one to actually run it from command prompt.

Comment: I tried os.system('echo sth like this'), didn't work.